# Let $f(x) = x^2$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $ x\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2,  & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\[2ex]
0, & x\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$ and  $g(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor -x \rfloor$

then find the limits :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x))=?$$

---

i know that 
$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1,  & x \notin \mathbb{Z} \\[2ex]
0, & x\in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}$$

Now what do I do ?

Comment: No. $$x \in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$$ does *not* imply that $$x\in \mathbb{Z}$$ $x=\pi$ is an example.

Comment: Consider an arbitrarily selected value of $x$ in the interval $(-1,0)$.  What is the value of $g(x)$?  What is the value of $f(g(x))$ for any value of $x$ in the interval $(-1,0)$?  Now... how about an arbitrarily selected value of $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: What you have written in your "I know that" section is wrong, it appears as though you meant to write $\color{red}{g}(x)=\begin{cases}-1&x\color{red}{\notin}\Bbb Z\\0&x\in \Bbb Z\end{cases}$, which is an important observation.  Using this observation, answer the questions I posed in my previous comment and reach your conclusion.

Comment: Please do not use cases in a title. It takes up a lot of room on the front page.

Comment: First of all if $n < x < n+1$ then $-(+1) < -x < -n$ so $\lfloor -x\rfloor = -\lceil x \rceil$ and $g(x) = -1$ if $x > 0$ and not an integer and $g(x) = 1$ if $x < 0$ and not an integer and $g(x) = 0$ if $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Is x approaching from the left or right?

Comment: Ooops.  My mistake $g(x) = -1$ for all $-1 < x < 0$ and $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: "Now what do I do ? "  Notice that $f(g(x)) = 1$ if $x \not \in \mathbb Z$ and $f(g(x)) = 0$ if $x\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x$ with $|x|<1$ you have correctly identified that $g(x)=-1$. Hence for all such $x$ we have $f(g(x))=f(-1)=1$ (as $-1$ is rational). From this it is possible to prove via the definition of a limit that $\lim_{x\to 0}f\circ g(x)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that $g(x)$ is always an integer, so that the "$x^2$" case of the definition of $f$ applies. And by closer observation, $f(g(x))=1$ around $0$. This is the requested limit.

---

Note that to compute the limit, the value of the function at $x=0$ does not matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

For $\lim_{x\to 0} WhatEverTheEff$ we may assume $-1 < x < 1$ and $x\ne 0$.

So if $x < 0$ then $g(x) = -1 + 0 = -1$ and $g(x) = 0 + -1 = -1$ if $x > 0$.

As $g(x) \in \mathbb Q$, $f(g(x)) = (g(x))^2 = 1^2 = 1$.

So $\lim_{x\to 0} f(g(x))= \lim_{x\to 0} 1 = 1$.

....

If you want to be formal.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = 1$.  If $0< |x-0| < \delta$ then $f(g(x)) = 1$ and so $|f(g(x)) - 1| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor-x\rfloor\in\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}$. In fact $g(x)=-1$ if $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore, if $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
f(g(x))=g(x)^2=1
$$